# How to create a Bing pushpin on my page that corresponds to the one on a map

Tags: bing-maps

I have a Bing map on my page that displays the location of each returned search result. Next to each result I'd like to put the corresponding pushpin image. So for example, on the first result I'd like to have an "A" pushpin next to it that looks exactly like the "A" pushpin on the map. Is there a way to retrieve that from the Bing service?

I can see that the pushpin is actually a combination of an "a" an "img" and a "div" - it would be ideal to be able to get that package returned from the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to get a copy of the base pushpin image that you are using to display your location. Once you have that then you can simply put this image in a div and overlay some text over it accordingly to mimic the look the layout of the pin on the map. This is pretty straight forward to do and a pretty common practice.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I was hoping it would be neatly packaged in a property of the Pushpin object or something. Oh well.